# Incrementing a Formatted Timer using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building a basic Timer Vue component. The timer increments by seconds, and the user can play and pause the timer on click. Here's the component:

```
<template>
    <div v-bind:class="{workspaceTimer: isRunning}">
        <a class="u-link-white" href="#" @click="toggleTimer">
            {{ time }}
            <span v-if="isRunning">
                Pause
            </span>
            <span v-else>
                Play
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['order'],
        data() {
            return {
                time: this.order.time_to_complete,
                isRunning: false,
                interval: null,
            }
        },
        watch: {
            time: function (newTime) {
                this.saveTime()
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleTimer() {
                if (this.isRunning) {
                    clearInterval(this.interval);
                } else {
                    this.interval = setInterval(this.incrementTime, 1000);
                }
                this.isRunning = !this.isRunning;
            },
            incrementTime() {
                this.time = parseInt(this.time) + 1;
            },
            formattedTime() {
                var sec_integer = parseInt(this.time, 10);
                var hours   = Math.floor(sec_integer / 3600);
                var minutes = Math.floor((sec_integer - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
                var seconds = sec_integer - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

                if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
                if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
                this.time = +minutes+':'+seconds;
            },
            saveTime: _.debounce(
                function () {
                    var self = this;
                    axios.put(location.pathname, {time_to_complete: self.time})
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log('timer: ' + response.data.time_to_complete);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + error);
                    })
                },
                1000
            )

    }
</script>
```

I'm storying the second count as an integer, but would like to display that second count as a mm:ss, and have that formatted value increment, e.g. 00:59 increments to 1:00.

I can easily format my second value using a method or computed property (see the `formattedTime()` method in that example), but I'm unsure of how to approach incrementing that string, and then formatting that incremented string. Do I need to watch for changes to that string, and then format the updated string?

Comment: `time` should be an integer counting seconds. `formattedTime` should be a [`computed`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. The answer was actually to use a local filter within my component:

```
filters: {
    formattedTime: function (value) {
        var sec_num = parseInt(value, 10);
        var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        //if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
        if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
        if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
        return +minutes+':'+seconds;
    }
},
```

And then apply that filter to my time variable: `{{ time | formattedTime }}`.